# Does casting objects clone the object, or is it still a reference in Java?

Tags: java, object, casting

I'm currently working on a game in Java, where I'm saving the entire game as an array in order to render it, and as such, I've noticed that sometimes objects seem to get entangled with some other object when I set them equal. Though after a bit of research, I have concluded that I'm just creating a new reference to that same object. I've tried various methods to avoid this issue and been rather succesfull. But one of the tequinces I tried along the way, was just casting the object to another type, as an rough example:

```
 public class Apple {

     boolean TasteLikaAnApple;

     public Apple {
        TasteLikeAnApple = true;
     }
     public ChangeTaste (boolean newTaste) {
        TasteLikeAnApple = newTaste;      
     }   
 }

 public class Pear{

     boolean TasteLikaAnApple;

     public Apple {
        TasteLikeAnApple = false;
     }
     public ChangeTaste (boolean newTaste) {
        TasteLikeAnApple = newTaste;      
     } 
 }
 public class main {
     public static void main (String[] args) {

         Apple fruit1 = new Apple();
         Pear fruit2 = new Pear();

         fruit2 = (Pear) fruit1;

         fruit2.ChangeTaste(false);
     }
 }
```

Now, I have no idea if I can cast the Pear to an Apple, but the code above should give you the rough idea of what I wonder:

**Does casting create a new object or will it just be another reference?**

Or in the context of the given code *Would fruit1 also have its field TasteLikeAnApple set to false?*

Comment: answer from @davidxxx alludes to this, but would be helpful to study inheritance. In his example public class Apple extends Fruit. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Does casting create a new object or will it just be another
>   reference?"

No one of them. Casting allows to assign from a type to a compatible  type (same hierarchy).

So your cast from Apple to Pear makes  no sense as Apple and Pear don't make part of the same hierarchy and more specifically here (downcast) an `Apple` is not a subclass of  `Pear` :

```
 Apple fruit1 = new Apple();
 Pear fruit2 = new Pear();

 fruit2 = (Pear) fruit1;
```

Suppose a Fruit class and its two subclasses : Apple and Pear.
You could so perform these downcasts :

```
 Fruit appleFruit = new Apple();
 Fruit pearFruit = new Pear();

 Pear pear = (Pear) pearFruit;
 Apple apple = (Apple) appleFruit;
```

or this upcast :

```
Apple apple = new Apple();
Fruit appleFruit = apple;
```